# How To Convert Anonymous Function with USE to PHP 5.2 Compatible One?

Tags: php, function, anonymous

I am a little confused on converting an anonymous function which is utilizing `USE()` to pass in variables over to a backwards compatible function for PHP < 5.3:

Here is the code I have:

```
/**
* Get all values from specific key in a multidimensional array
*
* @param $key string
* @param $arr array
* @return null|string|array
*/
function array_values_recursive($key, array $arr){

    $val = array();

    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){ 

        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);

    });

    return count($val) > 1 ? $val : array_pop($val);
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Easy! Stop using 5.2. `:I`

Comment: Yeah, I know, not my preference... dealing with client who simply won't go to 5.3... dumb.